# Python how to find correct result in string

Tags: python, temperature

I'm using Occidentalis v0.2 and calling modprobe with a python script to read out temperatures from one DS18B20!

I'm new to python as well so bear with me, this is a small part of my code:

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
  contentArray = []
  for line in f:
    contentArray.append (line)
f.close

s = contentArray[0]
if s.find('YES'):
  return contentArray[0]
else:
  return 88
```

Example: contentArray[0] can give results as:

```
68 01 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 05 : crc=3e NO
```

or:

```
68 01 4b 46 7f ff 08 10 05 : crc=05 YES
```

If the above code is wrong, how do I do to find the `YES`? Because this states
correct CRC. If I have a yes, I actually want to return `contentArray[1]` (which
contains the correct temperature value).

Comment: Such question is not really RaspberryPI related so I think you should use other SE page for it - like stackoverflow.

Comment: It's great you've found an answer, but as @KrzysztofAdamski says, the question is probably more appropriate on Stack Overflow. Let's close this.

Comment: You are both right, but in a sense, it's related to Occidentalis, that is a distro for rasp. Even if it's mostly just python question. :)

Comment: Hi guys. Although the post includes Raspberry Pi details, the actual question is about the semantics of Python. I think this would get better reception over at StackOverflow, so I'm going to move it over there.

Comment: If you use `with` you don't need to `close`.

Comment: In the case if no match, the idiomatic / pythonic thing to return would be `None`, I believe (or raise an exception which the caller can catch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I had to make this change in the code:

```
s = contentArray[0]
if s.find('YES') != -1:
  return contentArray[0]
else:
  return 88
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I will try out the .find command next time. I just scripted a little one-liner for the bash to save temperature readings. Of course the is much space for improvement.

```
while true; do echo -n "$(date '+%D %T'); " >> output.csv; cat /sys/devices/w1_bus_master1/*/w1_slave | grep -A 1 YES | grep -m 1 t= | cut -c30- >> output.csv; sleep 1; done
```

As you can see, the keywords "YES" and "t=" are found by the grep command.